subnetting within a single IP range (192.168.1.x) vs using multiple IP ranges (192.168.1.x, 192.168.2.x)
Use 1+3 routers to setup a 4 subnet small network.
Topology:
Main Wireless Router,R1, connected to ISP
  -- Device1 connected to R1
  -- Another wireless Router,R2
     -- Device2 connected to R2
  -- Another wireless Router,R3
     -- Device3 connected to R3
  -- Another wireless Router,R4
     -- Device4 connected to R4

My setup:
network            192.168.1.0 
first host address 192.168.1.1      router1 address
broadcast address  192.168.1.63
subnet mask        255.255.255.192

192.168.1.64 network address
192.168.1.65 router2 address
192.168.1.127
255.255.255.192

192.168.1.128 network address
192.168.1.129 router3 address
192.168.1.191
255.255.255.192

192.168.1.192 network address
192.168.1.193 router4 address
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.192

AI's answer:
Main Wireless Router,R1 (192.168.1.1)
（192.168.1.x/24）
  -- Device1 connected to R1
  -- Another wireless Router,R2 (192.168.1.2),  (192.168.2.1）
     (192.168.2.x/24）
     -- Device2 connected to R2
  -- Another wireless Router,R3 (192.168.1.3),  (192.168.3.1）
    (192.168.3.x/24）
     -- Device3 connected to R3
  -- Another wireless Router,R4 (192.168.1.4), (192.168.4.1）
    (192.168.4.x/24)
     -- Device4 connected to R4

I was thinking that my setup is great and carefully crafted. Then AI's answer surprised me. AI's setting also seems work and so much simpler.
And I started to ask myself, are there any advantages of my setup? Well, I can't think of any.
Can you give some opinions? Thanks

are there any advantages of my setup One I could think of is that yours marginally reduce the chance that there would be subnet conflict if you need to connect to some VPN / remote sites. And maybe you'll find it easier to remember your devices private IPs' when they are all 192.168.1.x.

@TomYan, its interesting you say that, because I had an exactly opposite feeling on the exact same points ;-). using the 192.168.1.x space makes it much more likely to have an addressing collision than 192.168.3.x (since every home router uses 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x or 192.168.254.x out of box), and I feel like it would be easier to remember the specific ranges if every network had its own unique 3rd octet.

@FrankThomas Well, as per his post regardless of which solution he choose, 192.168.1.0/24 would be used anyway, and with AI's answer, 192.168.{2,3,4}.0/24 would be "occupied" additionally. And what I was thinking was like, he would need to remember just one number (of range 1-254) per host with his own solution. In other words, he doesn't need to remember which network a host resides in, at least not for most of the time.

That's effectively the same setup. The only functional difference between your /26 and the other person's /24 is that the latter is larger.
There's nothing special about the /24 boundary – there was a difference long ago, i.e. in the 1980s when "classful" routing was still commonplace and your plan of subnetting what used to be known as a "class C network" would've needed more modern equipment than the other person's choice of multiple regular "class Cs" – but all of that has completely gone away by now, and there aren't any more routers or PCs that use inherent address classes.
Assuming the network is stand-alone, the network equipment is only aware of the end result and completely unaware that you started by subdividing an "192.168.1.x" range – it was an arbitrary range in the first place. (In both cases the setup uses only a small part of the actual 192.168./16 "reserved for private use" range.)
That being said, if your setup were meant to be integrated into a larger network, then working within a range that can be summarized to a single CIDR prefix is a food idea, as then the rest of the broader network only needs to keep track of a single /24 route towards your entire setup, whereas the other person's subnet choices don't fit nicely under a single CIDR – but if they were numbered 0..3 instead of 1..4, they would fit into a /22, so in the end both are still the same setup.
